# How to filter array of objects by timestamp attribute (code alternative to SQL lag over partition by - command)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

So I'm writing the code for apache spark which executes on the java virtual machine. It has Spark SQL which let the user write SQL expressions on collections of objects.

SQL command I am trying to query is too complicated for spark's engine so I am trying to find alternative using code not SQL.

I am writing a script to check if my data streamers streamed every 12 hours

So example data looks like this:

```
sourceId          streamedAt
----------------------------------
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:10
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:13
station_1      2019-06-02 21:05:10
station_1      2019-06-02 21:08:15
station_2      2019-06-02 09:30:10
station_2      2019-06-02 09:31:10
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:11
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:12
```

You can think of this as an array of StreamerEvent objects:

```
class StreamerEvent {
    String sourceId;
    Date streamedAt;
}
```

I need to search through the collection and for each streamer and stream which will last for a few minutes(this happens every 12 hours +- some time) get only the first one out of that particular streaming interval. So my array now looks like this:

```
sourceId          streamedAt
----------------------------------
station_1      2019-06-02 09:01:10
station_1      2019-06-02 21:05:10
station_2      2019-06-02 09:30:10
station_2      2019-06-02 21:40:11
```

So my SQL query for this was:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM (select sourceId, streamedAt, lag(streamedAt, 1) over(partition by sourceId order by streamedAt) as prev_streamedAt from streaming_data) streaming_data where prev_streamedAt is null or prev_streamedAt < streamedAt - interval 11 hour")
```

But it doesn't work on streaming data, only on static.

Can somebody give some hint on how to approach this using java/scala collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I found the solution to this problem.

I just needed to round my time part of the timestamp column as follows:

```
2019-06-02 09:01:10 => 2019-06-02 09:00:00
```

To do that I used org.joda.time library inside scala.

After that, I just used to select distinct by both columns.

Also in spark, an even better solution is to use 'dropduplicates()' function on the given dataframe.